# How to import jQuery only in certain modules with Webpack 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, es6-modules

I'm using Webpack 4 in a Codeigniter project. A lot of my Javascript code still depends on jQuery (installed through npm), so I have this Webpack configuration:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
}),
```

It works, but I'm planning to ditch jQuery, or at least to depend less on it, so instead of importing it globally, I would like to import it only in the modules where it's needed.
I tried removing the above config and added it in a module:

```
import { $, jQuery } from 'jquery';
import Dropzone from 'dropzone';
```

When loading the page I receive this error in the console:

```
myDropzone.js:95 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (myDropzone.js:95)
at r (bootstrap:76)
at t (bootstrap:43)
at bootstrap:134
at bootstrap:134
```

The code causing the error:

```
$('.dropzone').each(function () {  // <--- this line
  $(this).dropzone(config);
});
```

In the console I tried checking for `$` and `jQuery` and the first one works fine, but with jQuery I get an error saying that it's not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I am pretty sure the following happens:

You are loading the jQuery dropzone plugin somewhere high up in the dependencies tree, probably loaded by some other package. The plugin expects to find the jQuery object in the global scope, in order to attach itself to it (hence giving you access to the `$().dropzone` method, see [here](https://github.com/danielgindi/jquery.dropzone/blob/master/src/index.js#L213) ). By using the ProvidePlugin when the dropzone plugin tries to attach itself onto the jQuery object, there is no problem

However since you are now removing the `ProvidePlugin` the dropzone plugin never manages to attach itself and so there is no `$().dropzone` method available for use, so you get that error

Long story short, as long as you are depending on external code that assumes that jQuery is loaded in the global scope, you cannot truly eliminate the usage of `webpack.ProvidePlugin`, unless of course you directly modify the source code of those dependencies.

Comment: I'm not using bootstrap, though. Not sure what the "bootstrap" in the console means, but it's not referred to the framework. As you can see it's not a file, unlike `myDropzone.js`. If I click on the error it points to lines in the webpack code

Comment: Yeah, you are right. What I told you still stands though, regardless of whether you are using bootstrap or not, so make sure you are not using something that expects to find jQuery in the global scope

Comment: but I'm importing jquery right on top of the script where the error is being thrown. According to what you are saying, which to me sounds correct, that script should run and I should receive an error in some other parts of the code where jquery is not detected

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried `import $ from 'jquery'` instead of `import { jQuery, $ } from 'jquery'` ? 

Comment: yes, it's what Cody G. suggested in his answer. When I do that I get another error: `Uncaught TypeError: s(...)(...).dropzone is not a function`

Comment: Are you sure you have you loaded the dropzone plugin for jQuery? If you have not, it's normal that it cannot find any `dropzone` method on the jQuery object

Comment: I explain it in the comment to the other answer: simply by using `ProvidePlugin` to import `jQuery`, so without changing anything in the `dropzone` script, it works, so the issue can't be with dropzone

Comment: Ok, I am pretty sure the following happens: You are loading the jQuery `dropzone` plugin somewhere high up in the dependencies tree, probably loaded by some other package, I don't know. The plugin expects to find the jQuery in the global scope, in order to attach itself to it (hence giving you access to the `$().dropzone` method, see https://github.com/danielgindi/jquery.dropzone/blob/master/src/index.js#L213 ). By using the `ProvidePlugin` when the `dropzone` plugin tries to attach itself onto the jQuery object, there is no problem.

Comment: However since you are now removing the `ProvidePlugin` the `dropzone` plugin never manages to attach itself and so there is no `$().dropzone` method available for use, so you get that error.

Comment: I solved it. You were right in the comment before the last one. The problem wasn't exactly in the Dropzone plugin, but there was another plugin which needed jQuery and I was importing it after that. Maybe you can edit your answer including the comment so I can accept it. Anyway, thanks for the patience and the help

Comment: Done. So, how did you solve this? Did you stick with `ProvidePlugin` in the end?

Comment: ah, right, sorry. Basically I had an entry point like this: `import 'jqueryPlugin'; import 'myScript; import 'myDropzoneScript';`
The problem was in myScript, which depended on jqueryPlugin. So I moved the `import jqueryPlugin` (together with jQuery) inside `myScript`. This way I can avoid the ProvidePlugin, import jQuery only where I need it

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

Comment: I get a different error: `Uncaught TypeError: s(...)(...).dropzone is not a function`. It's basically the line next to the one I indicated in the answer. So, this way the problem seems to be with Dropzone, but just to be sure I tried again with ProvidePlugin and I get no errors and Dropzone works fine